# How to hide rows based on a cell's value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following issue: let's say I have a formula in cell A1. If the value is greater than or equal to 0.5, I want rows 2-4 hidden. Here's what I have currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$A$1"
        Rows("2:4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target >= 0.5)
End Select

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Target.Address
    Case "$A$1"
        If Target.Value >= 0.5 Then Rows("2:4").Hidden = True
End Select

End Sub
```

If you want to keep your style of coding, you can use the line below:

```
Rows("2:4").Hidden = (Target.Value >= 0.5)
```

Comment: @bandiras have you tried my code above ? if it's working for you, then you should mark my answer as "ANSWER"  (click the check mark next to my answer)